# Error when invoking AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ibm-cloud

**EDIT**

CHEC HERE MY EDITED POST with the JSONP issue i get this error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
     $.ajax({

  url: "https://brsv2-6855bc66.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/vacationsRuleApp/1.0/vacationsRuleProject/1.0",

        // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
        jsonp: "callback",

        // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",

        // Tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
        data: {
            "employeeID": "jujuju",
            "loanAmount": 10517320,
            "theEmployee": {
                "seniority": 3,
                "annualSalary": 10517320,
                "nbOfExtraVacationDaysBasedOnSeniority": 10517320
                    },
            "creditAmount": 20000,
            "__DecisionID__": "string",
            "AnnualSalary": 20000
                    },

        // Work with the response
        success: function( response ) {
            alert("Success");
            console.log( response ); // server response
        },
        fail: function(response){
            alert("Fail");
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
```

Comment: That url returns an error

Comment: what type of error ?

Comment: 404 Not Found: Requested route ('brsv20cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net') does not exist.

Comment: i created another service instance and tried it , same results ?? what's the problem then ?

Comment: Server problem - not a problem (necessarily) with your javascript. Try to find out what's wrong with the server-side data. CHeck the URL in the $.ajax call directly in your browser to make sure you're getting the data you expect.

Comment: you mean a problem with ibm itself ?

Comment: I really have no idea what your server side structure is but that URL you're putting in the ajax call is no good. You need to fix the server output at that URL

Comment: i can't understand what you mean by fix the server output at that URL?         you mean try pasting this  url:"https://brsv20cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/vacationsRuleApp/164.0/vacationsRuleProject/1.0" in my chrome browser ?

Comment: Where did you get that URL from?

Comment: @OmarAbdelMeneimZaki, what do you not understand when you get a 404 not found error? the host you put in the request, is not found. https://brsv20cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net/ - click it!

Comment: Where does brsv20cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net come from?  The page is returning a 404.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @JeffSloyer i swear it's the execution endpoint give on the services detail page

Comment: So it looks like you are getting a CORS error... To work around this you can use JSONP to fetch the data. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: use this instead of the ajax call listed above ??

Comment: the problem is when i go to the testing page of the business rules service or through the explorer tab in the rule execution server the json object is there and i can run tests very normally but this url returns an error i just want to access the json object in the business rules service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ideally be making this requests server side in Bluemix and then using your Bluemix app to proxy the request to your client side app.  You are getting the CORS error because browsers do not allow you to request resources from different domains.

Additionally the Business Rules service looks like it does not allow CORS.  You will need to write some server side code to proxy your request.

I have have posted some code below as well as gists on Github to help you with isolating your issue.

Grab both of the files and put them in a directory and modify 2 lines in `app.js` that have the username and password for Business Rules.

**package.json** (https://gist.github.com/jsloyer/2bf436f342e1d24c3099)

```
{
  "name": "bluemix-business-rules",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.10.8",
    "restler": "~3.2.2",
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10"
  },
  "author": "IBM Corp.",
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Jeff Sloyer",
      "email": "jbsloyer@us.ibm.com"
    }
  ],
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

**app.js** (https://gist.github.com/jsloyer/e5a953cf5691a4aeefc2)

```
var app = require("express")(),
    restler = require("restler");


app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    var json = {
        "employeeID": "jujuju",
        "loanAmount": 10517320,
        "theEmployee": {
            "seniority": 3,
            "annualSalary": 10517320,
            "nbOfExtraVacationDaysBasedOnSeniority": 10517320
        },
        "creditAmount": 20000,
        "__DecisionID__": "string",
        "AnnualSalary": 20000
    };
    var options = {
        username: "replaceme",
        password: "replaceme"
    };
    var url = "https://brsv2-6855bc66.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest" + "/vacationsRuleApp/1.0/vacationsRuleProject/json";
    restler.postJson(url, json, options).on('complete', function(data) {
        response.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080);
```

Then run `cf push businessrules-vacationsRuleApp`.

Open your web browser and navigate to the url it gives you.  Hopefully we can try to debug whats going on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84691/discussion-on-answer-by-jeff-sloyer-error-when-invoking-ajax-call).

Answer (score 0):

By default, a browser will not allow javascript to make a call to another domain "brsv20cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net", unless the brsv20cc90e37 application implemented CORS - basically just have this header in its response:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

The * indicates that all domains are allowed to call this. You can also specify the exact domain instead.

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Lots of great information available online if you research "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

In this case, where you do not own the brsv20cc90e37 application, you should call the brsv20cc90e37 API using server side code instead of client side javascript. Some APIs, like this one, are not meant to be called from the browser, so there is no reason for them to implement CORS.

Comment: where do i have to include this statement:

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: Omar, you should connect to this business rules service using sever side code. Client side JavaScript will not work (it's also not safe because you are passing private credentials to your end user)

Comment: and how can i do that ?!?!?!?!??! i already built my application on mobilefirst how to integrate ?!?!

Comment: i'm really fed up from bluemix and the services !